# How to get the exact matched keyword in MySQL MATCH() AGAINST() search?

Tags: mysql, regex, full-text-search, match, against

I am performing a search in mysql using `MATCH()` and `AGAINST()` function with multiple keyword. How to know which keyword matched for the search.

```
SELECT ... , MATCH(n.s_body_from_rss, n.s_full_body) AGAINST("LIST OF KEYWORDS' IN BOOLEAN MODE") AS relevance
```

This `relevance` show a numeric value rather than the matched keyword.

Any suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the result array and then using loop (for|foreach) in php match the string using the same keyword list in preg_match_all() i.e.  [assuming **KEYWORD_LIST** is in ',' separated value]

```
 preg_match_all('/\b'.str_replace(',','\b|\b', **KEYWORD_LIST**).'\b/iu',$string,$match);
 $matched_keyword = array_unique($match[0]);
```

the **$matched_keyword** array will provide the desire matched keyword list.

> *`This is a probable solution in php instead of MySQL query itself`*

Comment: Seems a better solution. Thanks